# Building crafty chess engine on a Mac

Tags: c, macos, compilation

fellow coders, I downloaded crafty from here http://craftychess.com/crafty-25.0.zip and tried to build it on a Mac (Xcode installed) from the command line.

I execute make -j unix-clang and got the following error:

```
error: *.profraw: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [unix-clang] Error 1
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

In the Makefile unix-clang is defined like this:

unix-clang:

```
@/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/llvm-profdata merge -output=crafty.profdata *.profraw
$(MAKE) -j target=UNIX \ 
    CC=clang CXX=clang++ \ 
    opt='-DTEST -DINLINEASM -DPOPCNT -DCPUS=4' \ 
    CFLAGS='-Wall -Wno-array-bounds -pipe -O3 \
        -fprofile-instr-use=crafty.profdata' \
    CXFLAGS='-Wall -Wno-array-bounds -pipe -O3 \
        -fprofile-instr-use=crafty.profdata' \
    LDFLAGS='$(LDFLAGS) -fprofile-use -lstdc++' \
    crafty-make
```

Could anyone help?

I have tried googling the problem but everything i found was for Windows.

thanks

Update Jan 13:

$ make profile produces the following:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -j unix-clang-profile
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -j target=UNIX \
        CC=clang CXX=clang++ \
         opt='-DTEST -DINLINEASM -DPOPCNT -DCPUS=4' \
         CFLAGS='-Wall -Wno-array-bounds -pipe -O3 \
        -fprofile-instr-generate' \
         CXFLAGS='-Wall -Wno-array-bounds -pipe -O3 \
        -fprofile-instr-generate' \
         LDFLAGS=' -fprofile-instr-generate -lstdc++ ' \
        crafty-make
  clang -Wall -Wno-array-bounds -pipe -O3       
  -fprofile-instr-generate -DTEST -DINLINEASM -DPOPCNT -DCPUS=4 -DUNIX -c crafty.c
  clang++ -c -Wall -Wno-array-bounds -pipe -O3      
  -fprofile-instr-generate -DTEST -DINLINEASM -DPOPCNT -DCPUS=4 -DUNIX egtb.cpp
 clang -fprofile-instr-generate -lstdc++  -o crafty crafty.o egtb.o -lm  
 Illegal instruction
 make: *** [profile] Error 132
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What CPU do you have? And is your OS 64-bit?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
$ make profile
$ ./crafty
```

Looks like a bug in the Makefile.

Edit:

Your CPU or OS doesn't support the assembly code so change the following lines in the Makefile:

```
unix-clang:
...
opt='-DTEST -DINLINEASM -DPOPCNT -DCPUS=4' \
...
```

to

```
unix-clang:
...
opt='-DTEST -DCPUS=4' \
...
```

and change

```
unix-clang-profile:
...
opt='-DTEST -DINLINEASM -DPOPCNT -DCPUS=4' \
...
```

to

```
unix-clang-profile:
...
opt='-DTEST -DCPUS=4' \
...
```

And redo make. You should also read the top portion of the Makefile for other info.